# What is wrong with this query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields: id | domainname | domain_certificate_no | keyvalue

An example for the output of a select statement can be as:

```
'57092', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com_1', '55525772666'
'57093', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com_2', '22225554186'
'57094', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com_3', '22444356259'
'97168', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_1', '55525772666'
'97169', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_2', '22225554186'
'97170', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_3', '22444356259’
```

I want to write a query to retrieve the number of repeated `keyvalue`, and which `keyvalue` that is associated with more than one `domain_certificate_no` with cert _1. So I wrote this:

```
select count(keyvalue), keyvalue from db.table group by (keyvalue) 
having count(keyvalue)>1 and domain_certificate_no like '%_1';
```

I get an error number 1054 saying unknown column `domain_certificate_no`. Can you tell me what is wrong? How can I write query to achieve my purpose ?

Comment: If its in a different table, include it in your FROM clause.

Comment: I don't see any reason to not trust mysql - if it says there is no such column, then there is no such column

Comment: have you correctly defined table name? "db.table"

Comment: Yes I defined the table correctly. And all in one table.

Answer (score 1):

Just about the logic:

```
SELECT COUNT(domain_certificate_no), keyvalue
FROM db.table 
WHERE domain_certificate_no LIKE '%_1'
GROUP BY keyvalue
HAVING COUNT(keyvalue)>1;
```

If there's still your unknown column error, please show the result of `DESC db.table;`

Cheers.

Comment: But, how can I improve the query to list every `domainname` along with the `keyvalue` so I can see all the domain names? When using group by, I don't see all the domain names that have the repeated key. In short, I need a way to find the repeated values and list them with the repetition.

Comment: In your solution, did you make `group by domain_certificate_no` purposefully ?

Comment: It doesn't work since `domain_certificate_no` is unique value. I guess that's why. But worked if I made `group by` with `domainname`.

Comment: Hi @JuryA , I just sticked to what you wanted to do in your problem description. But I'm realizing I took it the wrong way. Please check my upcoming update.

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` keyword should be in your `WHERE` clause

```
   SELECT domain_certificate_no, COUNT(keyvalue) 
     FROM db.table 
    WHERE domain_certificate_no LIKE '%_1'
 GROUP BY domain_certificate_no
   HAVING COUNT(keyvalue) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(keyvalue) AS keyvaluecount, keyvalue 
FROM 
    db.table 
HAVING
    keyvaluecount > 1 AND domain_certificate_no LIKE '%_1' 
GROUP BY 
    (keyvalue)
```

Comment: You need a HAVING clause to compare an aggregate, or you need to do the aggregation in a sub-query.  And personally, I dislike that layout of SQL; it uses too much vertical space.

Comment: Apologies for the HAVING mistake. I only lay it out like that so its easier for everybody to read on here.

Comment: You should fix the HAVING issue.  The other is a personal whinge (by me). I find it harder to read than the more compact notations where the 'operands' of the clauses start on the same line.  That is a subjective view.  Clearly, some agree with me; two other answers show the layout I'd recommend (or more nearly the layout I'd recommend; neither is precisely as I'd format it, but the operands are on the same line as the main clauses).  As I said, it is subjective; your call on the format.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree heartily with Jonathan re `HAVING` but respectfully disagree with the observation re whitespace.

Comment: The HAVING mistake was because its 2am! Personally I agree with Jonathan's formatting, when I was at uni I always had to write queries in that format and I got into the habit of writing them in that style when they going to be viewed by other people. For personal projects I don't normally use this practice.