# How to list all duplicate values using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields:

```
 id | domainname | domain_certificate_no | keyvalue
```

An example for the output of a select statement can be as:

```
 id    |  domainname               |  domain_certificate_no      |  keyvalue
 ===============================================================================
'57092', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com_1', '55525772666'
'57093', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com_2', '22225554186'
'57094', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com_3', '22444356259'
'97168', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_1', '55525772666'
'97169', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_2', '22225554186'
'97170', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_3', '22444356259’
```

The field `domain_certificate_no` is unique. I used `group by` to find the repeated `keyvalue` but what I actually need is not only how many occurrence for the `keyvalue` but also, I need to list the repeated value one by one along with the other fields in each record this value occurred. The thing that I could not achieve with `group by`. How can I do this.

Comment: Since you insist on repeating [this data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11856026/62576) in every question, it might help if you at least once indicated an example of the output you'd like to get, as well as what you've tried to do so far that isn't working.

Comment: What would be nice is if you provided your sample data as a MySQL insert statement that I could just paste into MySQL to test some sample queries for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but I think this would work just off the top of my head

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE keyvalue IN (
      SELECT keyvalue FROM table GROUP BY keyvalue HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

an alternative from the others' answer is the `INNER JOIN` from a derived query.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    myTable a
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT keyValue
                FROM myTable
                GROUP BY keyValue
                HAVING COUNT(keyValue) > 1
            ) b 
                ON a.keyValue = b.keyValue
```

Comment: Without testing and not being a DBA is that more efficient generally than the query I answered with

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test the code, but it should help you more ;)

```
select group_concat(id) as all_id, group_concat(domainname) as all_domains, group_concat(domain_certificate_no) as all_certificats , keyvalue, count(keyvalue) from table x
group by keyvalue
order by count(keyvalue)
```

Comment: If there are more than 1024 values in the group, you'll need to change the `group_concat_max_len` value in the my.cnf. Also, this could be really, really hard to read.